# Prediction with optional parameters

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, prediction, ai

I want to build a machine learning model that has 25 input feature and two labels (my problem is a regression task if it makes any difference), to my knowledge since I have two labels I need two models, one for each label. No problem with that. However, during prediction, the user might not supply all the 25 inputs. Instead, the user can supply and number of features between 3 to all, how to deal with this problem?

I thought about using 0 for the missing values. However, I don't think that it makes any sense,as the original data also have zeros in some columns. Also, I thought about training a model on the run  when a new combination of features is supplied by the user. However, the combinations are unlimited almost (25!)

Currently, I am planning to use CatBoost regression as it deals automatically with categorical features , but I have no problem with using a deep learning or other kind of models

Side note: the training data set has all the 25 features without any missing data, the issue is when the model is used in prediction